# Is it allowed to insult sinners?

Tags: quran, reference-request

Someone who is not a Muslim (yet?) but she loves Islam, said "If Qur'an says do not insult people, it means DO NOT INSULT PEOPLE.", I'm looking for verses where it says in Qur'an. If anyone knows some, please share me link.

People like non-Muslims, who do wrongdoers like they support homosexuality or drink alcohols.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refering to the two verses below you can easily tell that we should abstain from insulting any one whether it was a non believer or a believer:

> 6:108 And do not insult those they invoke other than Allah , lest they
>   insult Allah in enmity without knowledge. Thus We have made pleasing
>   to every community their deeds. Then to their Lord is their return,
>   and He will inform them about what they used to do.
>
> 49:11 O you who have believed, let not a people ridicule [another]
>   people; perhaps they may be better than them; nor let women ridicule
>   [other] women; perhaps they may be better than them. And do not insult
>   one another and do not call each other by [offensive] nicknames.
>   Wretched is the name of disobedience after [one's] faith. And whoever
>   does not repent - then it is those who are the wrongdoers.

Even if someone verbally abuses us that still does not give us the right to abuse them as well as two wrongs don't make a right and we will be rewarded for our patience

> "The Muslim who mixes with the people and bears patiently their
>   hurtful words, is better than one who does not mix with people and
>   does not show patience under their abuse." (Mishkat, Book: Ethics, ch.
>   'Gentleness, modesty and good behaviour')
>
> (3:185) "You will certainly hear much abuse from the followers of
>   previous books and from the idol-worshipping people. And if you are
>   patient and keep your duty -- this is surely a matter of great
>   resolution."

This is one of my favourite hadeeths, it indicates that we should have more control over our speech and think of what we are about to say before saying it for it may harm someone:

> The Messenger of Allah, Muhammed - SallAllahu 'alaihi wa sallam -
>   said, “Whoever believes in Allah and the Last Day should speak good or
>   keep silent.”

We are not limited to just abstaining from verbal insults rather from back biting others and speaking ill of them in their absence:

> Narrated by Mughira bin Shu’ba - radiAllahu' anhu - : The Prophet -
>   SallAllahu 'alaihi wa sallam - said,  “Allah has forbidden for you:(1)
>   to be undutiful to your mothers, (2) to bury your daughters alive, (3)
>   not to pay the rights of the poor and others (i.e. charity) and (4) to
>   beg of men. And Allah has hated for you: (1) Qil and Qal (sinful and
>   useless talk, like backbiting or that one talks too much about
>   others), (2) to ask too many questions (in disputed religious matters,
>   etc.), (3) to waste your wealth (by extravagance with lack of wisdom
>   and thinking).” - Sahih al-Bukhari [3:591]

Allah Knows best, inshalah this helped

Comment: Isn't Qur'an 6:108 talking about insulting their Gods?

Comment: @azam I looked into the tafseer, I need to do more research on it I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Bismillah,

She is right, we are not supposed to insult other people regardless of their beliefs. Allah (SWT) says in Surat Al-An'am [[6:108]](http://quran.com/6/108)

[image]

> And do not insult those they invoke other than Allah , lest they
>   insult Allah in enmity without knowledge. Thus We have made pleasing
>   to every community their deeds. Then to their Lord is their return,
>   and He will inform them about what they used to do.

If you want a better understanding of this verse, please consider reading the interpretation.

Allah knows best!

Comment: Thank you. Should I apologize to very few non-Muslims for saying homosexulity is a sin?

Comment: I'm sorry I did not understand your question. However, if you've insulted someone that you know personally, it's better if you apologize.

Comment: @sho89 they are free to believe that its not a sin but that does not mean that we shall give up the freedom of having our own beliefs, we do think it is a sin but that does not mean that we will abuse homosexuals physically or verbally only god can judge its not our job! why should you apologize we are not insulting them by calling it a sin we are just sticking to our beliefs!

Comment: Isn't this verse talking about insulting their Gods?

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, I think it is critical to understand from an Islamic standpoint that drinking alcohol is very different than supporting homosexuality. A drinking muslim is still a Muslim who sins; as long as he/she is not claiming drinking is halal. On the other hand —while knowing it is very clearly haram in Islam— claiming that homosexuality is OK or defending/supporting it is claiming something that Allâh made “haram” as “helal”. A Muslim cannot decree something, which Allâh decreed filthy, clean.

Shortly, sinning is of course not desirable, but calling something, which Allâh (S.W.T) decrees dirty/filthy, OK is contradicting Allâh’s (J.J) word, which —if done knowingly (knowing that Allaah has decreed it a sin— can put one’s belief in jeopardy. As Muslims we have to be extremely vigilant on this regard.

Please do not call something halal or haram if you are not sure about it. If you are unsure about it, please do not defend/support things that might be regarded as evil by your Creator.

Allaah (S.W.T) knows the best.

Answer (score -1):

Is it better to bring people together in the world or is it Ok to bring people hate, confusion and or an example of what not to do? If you look at common sense, human being can figure out that one must conduct themselves to reflect on a treatment of other people as people would want to be treated. Go back 2ooo years, go back 1400 years, can we look at history to understand that the ability to use our brain, our heart and our ability to move this world forward towards understanding starts with each of us taking accountability for ourselves. If we look around the world, do we not see something much greater than a difference in belief system, mindsets from the environment of confusion that allows the world to remain in hate instead of with love and understanding. Not only much greater but also our own missed opportunity to realize that change starts with each of us. Hajj should begin with our journey inside to look at the world not through the limited understanding of man but through the direction that God gave to man within the Mecca Qur'an, Peace, Understanding and Love. Man has felt the need to insult others based on a lack of education, lack of confidence, lack of maturity and a lack of understanding that we must think for ourselves when we seek direction and understanding since emotions make fool and moments of regret.